# Скрипт преобразования ajax запроса в Curl и добавление ему параметров

Tags: php, ajax, curl

подскажите как можно написать скрипт(для локального сервера), который будет забирать ajax запрос идущий к нему, и добавлять ему заголовок, а также изменять один параметр тела(json) и перенаправлять измененный запрос уже на сервер с API. Можно, кто-то видел подобно? Вот условная схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насчёт безопасности, я буду брать пароль и логин  из сессии, и соответственно, отсеку "злые" запросы.

Comment: Никак. Всё что идёт из браузера доступно пользователю этого браузера.

Comment: Я и говорю, что хочу хранить токен на сервере, как мне написать код на PHP, который просто будет пересылать ajax запрос по ссылке и изменять параметр в header?

Comment: А как сервер будет определять к какому запросу добавлять или нет? Что если кто-то будет просто так отсылать эти запросы, не будучи клиентом, а сервер будет автоматом туда пихать ключ? Хреновый, костыльный метод ...

Comment: А зачем его скрывать?

Comment: Выполнять запрос в как я понимаю стороннее апи на стороне сервера, а со стороны фронта дергать свой сервер. Это обычно называется проксированием.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov аргумент, подскажите как лучше сделать?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov там надо передать id user, я могу плюсом добавлять id на внутреннем сервере которое берётся из сессии, а для этого нужен пароль, получается так будет защита?

Comment: Да, так будет лучше. Используйте сессию для авторизации пользователя и получения его ID, и ТОЛЬКО после этого давайте ему возможность вызвать сторонний URL с вашим токеном.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, хорошо, но скрипт php не подскажете, который заберет запрос и преобразует?

Comment: Большая проблема в том, что я знаю только ajax, Curl понимания не очень много

Comment: Поэтому и хочу перенаправлять ajax запрос, с некими изменениями, плюс так, можно избавится от большого количества PHP файлов под каждый запрос

Comment: @AlexeyTen думаю не очень хорошо, оставлять token от API любому пользователю

Comment: Зависит от токена и API. И вообще лучше документацию почитать. Частотомеры привязаны к домену и никакой пользы на другом домене от них не будет, так что-то скрывать нечего

Comment: @AlexeyTen Это моё API, вернее для меня сделанное, и даже если оно привязанно к домену,  я сам могу взять изменить ajax запрос и выполнить у себя, и без защиты даже задать левому пользователю, то чего он не делал, так что эта защита нужна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, спустя 2 дня и 2 вопроса на Stackoverflow, у меня получился рабочий код (идеи по оптимизации приветствуются, буду сильно благодарен). Исходник:

```js
require "../db.php";       

$urlApi = 'http://my_api/api';
$token = 'mytoken';

// Забираем пользователя и изменяем его id, чтобы нельзя было обратится за другого
$login = $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;
$var = R::findOne('users', 'WHERE `login`=?', [$login]);

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(); 

$arOptions = [
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'x-inclo-token:' . $token,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ],
];

if (isset($_POST)){ 
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ // Разбираем массив $_POST
    if ($key == 'url_api'){
      $urlApi = $urlApi . $value;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlApi);
    }
    if ($key == 'type'){ 
      if ($value == 'post'){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $MyFlag = 1;
      }else if($value == 'get'){ 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
        $MyFlag = 0;
      }
    }
    $data[$key] = $value;
    // $a[$key]=$value; 
  }
  $data['id'] = $var->id;
}    
if ($MyFlag == 1){
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
}
curl_setopt_array($ch, $arOptions);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);     
$res = json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo ($res);
```

Ajax запрос со страницы пользователя:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "./Scripts/Interaction_Api.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'dataString',
  datatype: 'json',
  data: {
    type: 'post',
    url_api: '/set',
    setname: array[0],
    clo: array[1],
    geo: ['ru'],
    trafficsource: array[3],
    paranoia: true,
    streamlink: array[5],
  },success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    if (data == 200){
      return true;
    }else if(data == 400){
      return false;
    }else if (data == 403 && flag == 0){
      // Если ошибка авторизации отправим ещё раз
      Send_set_api(ArraySet, 1);
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Теперь конечно остается вопрос, насколько это сильно обезопасит, насколько теперь сложно вытащить токен и адрес сервера. ну и конечно не защищает от DDOS атак на сервер API

Comment: Согласен, безопасностью тут и не пахло. У вас можно задать для свой адрес апи, чтобы сервер сам прислал токен прямо по заданному в $POST адресу

Comment: @DiD честно говоря не понял, можно подробнее? Тут опять же стоит вспомнить что у меня нет доступа к API

Comment: Насколько легко получить серверный файл взаимодействия с api?

Comment: Дело не в API.  Дело в том, как вы валидируете параметры POST. На самом деле curl при определенных параметрах вполне может даже сделать запросы серверу самому себе и выдать любой файл с вашего сервера в качестве ответа на запрос.

Comment: @DiD Php stip_tags(), от этого ни как не спасёт) Я прав

Comment: На самом деле php не лучшим образом подходит под такие задачи. По сути у вас классический proxy-сервер, коих описано в миллионах статей на том же nodejs. Там это реализуется просто и наглядно. Но я бы выбрал go или rust.

Comment: @DiD понимаю, но увы мне стек менять поздно, хотя учту в дальнейшем) Что можете порекомендовать сейчас?

Comment: Чтобы не быть голословным, вот пример реализации почти того же самого что и у вас но на [nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354642/14255891)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131082/discussion-between-did-and-artemgh).