# Javascript как разобрать ответ сервера

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно разобрать с помощью Js, вот такой пример запроса? (Обычно я разбирал ответы без заголовков). Пример ответа сервера:

```js
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 97
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 16:47:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"body should have required property 'user_id'"}
```

Мне всегда надо будет доставать только значение `statusCode`

P.S не обращайте внимание на ошибку

Comment: А зачем приходит ответ в таком виде?

Comment: Видимо накосячил с CUrl запросом(первый раз его использую) Вот тут код: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344425/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-curl-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2, если вас не затруднит перейти

Comment: CURLOPT_HEADER   false надо... потому что "CURLOPT_HEADER true для включения заголовков в вывод."

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю почему ответ приходит в таком виде. Это не правильно. Но если надо, может попробовать так:

```js
let text = `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 97
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 16:47:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"body should have required property 'user_id'"}`;

let json = JSON.parse(text.substr(text.indexOf('{')));
console.log(json.statusCode);
```

---

с регуляркой:

```js
let text = `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 97
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Nov 2021 16:47:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"body should have required property 'user_id'"}`;

var regex = /{.*?}/g;
var json = JSON.parse(regex.exec(text));
console.log(json.statusCode);
```